# Python printing many times over for single print

Tags: python

My code is:

```py
for n in range(1,10000000):  
    if n>1:
        for i in range(2,n):
            if n % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            v = 2+n
            for i in range(2,v):
                if v % i == 0:
                    break  
                else:
                    print(n,v)
```

When I run the code, it prints multiple of each number with each having a random number of the particular two numbers. I am having trouble fixing the code. I have asked others who are more well-versed in coding than I am, but they were unable to solve the problem. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you want to do? what is your expected output? what output are you getting?

Comment: @JorgeMorgado Looks like they are trying to get pairs of prime numbers that are separated by 2. The problem is that the final `else` is at the wrong indentation level and needs to pair with the `for` (similar to the first `else`), not the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is not random, but as the desired output is not defined, I'll start with explaining what the current algorithm actually does;
The code can be split in to two main functionalities. The first functionality looks for a prime number `n`. If `n` is not prime, the code continues to the next `n`:

```
for n in range(1,10000000):
 if n>1:

   for i in range(2,n):
      if n % i == 0:
          break
```

The second functionality comes into play only if `n` is prime (a clever use of `for..else`). It will now check to see if `n+2` is divisible by any number from 2 up to `n+1`. I took the liberty of replacing `v` with `n+2` in the following snippet, as I believe it makes things a bit clearer;

```
   else:
       #v = 2+n  # taking liberty..
       for i in range(2, n+2):
           if (n+2) % i == 0:
               break  
           else:
               print(n, n+2)
```

To illustrate what actually happens, I chose primes `5`, `7`, `11`, and `23`, as I believe these four can explain the output pretty well. Starting with 5:

```
 for i in range(2, 7):  # i -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
     if (7) % i == 0:
         break
     else:
         print(5, 7)
```

In the snippet above, `5 7` will be printed 5 times, once for each `i` in the loop, as 7 is a prime and is not divisible by any given `i`.

```
 for i in range(2, 9):  # i -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
     if (9) % i == 0:
         break
     else:
         print(7, 9)
```

Here you will find that `7 9` is only printed once, because 9 is not divisible by 2, but it is divisible by 3 - in which case, the loop breaks, and continues to the next prime `n`. Now let's look at `n=11`:

```
 for i in range(2, 13):  # i -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
     if (13) % i == 0:
         break
     else:
         print(11, 13)
```

Here, like with `n=5`, `n+2` is also prime (13). As it is not divisible by any number in `i`, the sequence `11 13` will be printed the length of `i`, which is 11 (it will always be `n`, as we start from 2, and add 2 to `n`).

```
 for i in range(2, 25):  # i -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
     if (25) % i == 0:
         break
     else:
         print(23, 25)
```

This is the first interesting case in the realm of lower numbers. Up to 23, all `n+2` were either prime, or divisible by 3; they were printed `n` times, or just once. With `n=23`, the sequence `23 25` is printed 3 times, because 25 is not divisible by 2, 3, or 4 (3 prints), but it is divisible by 5, so now the loop breaks again, and continues to the next prime `n`.

Again, the resulting output you are looking for is not clear, but reading through previous comments I have to warn - this solution will not print two prime numbers separated by 2 (as @alani figured), it will simply ensure each line is printed just once:

```
for n in range(3,10000000):


     for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i == 0:
            break

     else:
         v = 2+n
         for i in range(3,v):
             if v % i:
                 print(n,v)
                 break
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it so it'll only print once each time, along with only going to the square root of each number as going past that is overkill

```
for n in range(2,10000000): #started at 2 instead of 1
  #removed if statement because i changed start from 1 to 2
  for i in range(2,int(n**0.5) + 2): #now goes to square root plus 1(to correct for automatic rounding down)
    if n % i == 0:
      break
           
    else:
      v = n + 2
      for f in range(2,int(v**0.5) + 2): #now goes to square root plus 1(to correct for automatic rounding down)
        if v % f == 0:
          break
        elif f == int(v**0.5) + 1: #changed else to elif with condition of being at last iterated integer
          print(n,v)
```

I didn't want to totally revamp your code but if you do want to make this more efficient, i would recommend creating a list of prime numbers you find(by appending each time you find one) and then using a for loop iterating over the list up to the square root of the current value(as iterating over composite numbers is inefficient, since they are multiples of the prime numbers)

Hopefully this is what you wanted, if not i can try to help further though, also please don't take my recommendation as criticism or anything, it's just my opinion on what might make your code run faster

Comment: It seems to me that micromoses' code works, but unfortunately, yours does not. Thank you so much for your answer. Both of you have helped a lot. Thank you!